# Using Python to extract string from title tag from html

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to extract every `something` within `title=" something"` in .html file below using python.

```
<a class="BoxA" href="https://www.somethingsomething1.com" title=" AppleJuce 50x 122L">
...
</a></td>
<a class="BoxA" href="https://www.somethingsomething2.com" title=" AppleJam 100x 300L ">
...
</a></td>
and so on
```

Based on my search I think I should use

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import re

with open(r'C:\Users\Me\Desktop\1.html', "rb") as f:
    page = f.read()
tree = html.fromstring(page)
Titles= tree.xpath(...)
```

but I'm having trouble with `...somecode` inside the  of  `Titles= tree.xpath(...somecode)`

Or is there any other way to do this? Thank you.

Also, I'd like to have `AppleJuce 50x` and their size `122L` stored in two different lists, but don't know how to find a number before whitespace from the end of a string.

This is what I have so far for splitting the strings:

```
for title in Titles:
    number = re.search('\d', title)
    Apple= [title[:number.start()]]  #?????Is this right?
    size = [title[number.start():]]  #?????Is this right?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
titleRegEx = r'title=\"([a-z\.\'A-Z0-9\s]*)\"'
findList = re.findall(titleRegEx, page)
appleList = []
sizeList = []
for item in findList:
    processedItem = item.lstrip().rstrip()
    processedItemList = processedItem.split(' ')
    appleList.append(processedItemList[0] + " "+ processedItemList[1])
    sizeList.append(processedItemList[2])
```

Comment: After reading the contents of the file into page variable, the above code gives you the required lists

Comment: Kindly edit your answer to include the comment. Good answers should explain what the code does and how it is relevant to the OPs question.

Comment: I tried your code and it worked! Only thing is I need to convert the html into a string with "page1 = page.decode('utf-8')". Thank you very much! I